# Most efficient method to detect color using OpenCV?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, image-processing, opencv

I setup an area of interest somewhere near the center of my image using:

```
Mat frame;
//frame has been initialized as a frame from a camera input
Rect roi= cvRect(frame.cols*.45, frame.rows*.45, 10, 8);
image_roi= frame(roi);
//I stoped here not knowing what to do next
```

I'm using a camera and at any time when I grab a frame, the ROI will be anywhere between 30% to 100% filled with my desired color, which is Red in this case. What is the most efficient method to know if Red is present in my current frame?

Solution:

```
image_roi= frame(roi);// a frame from my camera as a cv::Mat
cvtColor(image_roi, image_roi, CV_BGR2HSV);
thrs= new Mat(image_roi.rows, image_roi.cols, CV_8UC1);//allocate space for new img
inRange(image_roi, Scalar(0,100,100), Scalar(12,255,255), *thrs);//do hsv thresholding for red
for(int i= 0; i < thrs->rows; i++)//sum up
{
    for(int j=0; j < thrs->cols; j++)
    {
        sum= sum+ thrs->data[(thrs->rows)* i + j];
    }
}
if(sum> 100)//my application only cares about red
    cout<<"Red"<<endl;
else
    cout<<"White"<<endl;
sum=0;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you just want to know the percentage of red in the ROI. If that's not correct, please clarify.

I'd scan the ROI and convert each pixel into a better color space for color comparison, such as YCbCr, or HSV. I'd then count the number of pixels where the hue is within some delta of red's hue (usually 0 degrees on the color wheel). You might need to deal with some edge cases where the brightness or saturation are too low for a human to think they're red, even though technically they are, depending on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: TH.'s answer was more of what I was looking for but your method is easier to implement. I will modify my post to reflect the solution.

Answer (score 4):

This solution should address not only red but any *color distribution*:

1. Get a *color histogram* for your ROI, a bidimensional hue and saturation histogram (follow the example [here](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/histograms.html?highlight=calchist#cv2.calcHist)).
2. Use `calcBackProject` to [project the histogram back in the full image](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/histograms.html?highlight=calchist#calcbackproject). You will get *larger* values in pixels presenting a color near the *modes* of the histogram (in this case, reds).
3. Threshold the result to get the pixels that better match the distribution (in this case, the "best reds").

This solution can be used, for example, to get a simple but very functional *skin detector*.